# Why state is not updated after button click using hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Could you please tell me why state is not updated ? On button click I updated the state but when I console my state on setinterval  it is not updated why ?

Here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-shamir-8lmpo

```
 <button
        onClick={() => {
          setState({
            filters: {
              apps: "DDDDDDH",
              searchText: "12333",
              taskType: "",
              dateFrom: "",
              dateTo: "",
              status: ""
            }
          });
        }}
      >


useEffect(() => {
    console.log("===============");
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log(state);
    }, 10000);
  }, []);
```

`After button click  searchText: "12333",` searchtext should be `12333` in state but it is showing empty wny ?

Comment: It updates okay for me - https://i.imgur.com/mCKctHc.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens here is, The state is changing when the button gets clicked, but to render it in console setInterval should be cleared. try this!.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("===============");
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log(state);
    }, 10000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [state]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting state is async in React, instead of using interval, you need to track the state value `useEffect`'s dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
      console.log(state);
  }, [state]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using setInterval while you are updating state on button click?
Try this.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("===============");

    console.log(state);
  }, []);
```